# Return listBox items from function in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, return-value, return-type

I am trying to return the collection list of items in a list box from a function so that I can utilize the data in another function.

I had seen a method to loop through the collection and add it to a list, but is there a better way to do this so I don't have to loop through all of the values in the list?

```
public list<String> getListItems(){
    List<string> selectedList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items) {
       selectedList.Add(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that from the Forms ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx ) or Controls ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx ) case? The latter is an IList already that could probably be manipulated with some lambda expression.

Comment: this is coming from Forms. And I would like to shorten it so that I don't need to loop through the items list. What about returning `ListBox.ObjectCollection`? But then I need to use the forms library in my other class where it is not necessarily required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Cats<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) this way:

```
this.listBox1.Items.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

Or if you want `List<string>`:

```
this.listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: But this still requires the program to go through all of the items in the list. What about returning `ListBox.Objectcollection`? would it be worse to include the forms library in another class?

Comment: Its not a good idea to return `ListBox.ObjectCollection` because other libraries that want to use the result should add reference to system.windows.forms. Also `ListBox.ObjectCollection` is not a flexible type and usually you need to change it to list at last.

Comment: You are welcome :) Also don't worry about adding them to another listbox, you can simply use `listBox2.Items.AddRange()` to simply add them to another listbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ like this:

```
return listBox1
    .Items
    .Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Although this is less code, I think it is going to be more or less the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`Cast<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert each item of `Items` collection to an queryable object.

First add the namespace to use Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Try something like this:

```
public List<string> getListItems()
{
   return listBox1.Items.Cast<object>()
                        .Select(x => x.ToString())
                        .ToList();
}
```